# Keycloak - restrict the access to the admin console

Tags: keycloak, restriction

Is there any way to restrict the access to the keycloak admin console at the level of groups or user roles? The way of restriction by ip (and undertow filter to block external access), unfortunately, does not quite suit me. I will be very grateful for any advice!

I tried to create roles for security-admin-console and realm-management clients, but it didn't work, all the users still have access to admin console.

Comment: They have access, but can they login into it? normally users need specially permissions to login into the admin console, therefore the new users that you create should not be able to login to it. If by access you mean having access to the login page then there is no way that you can forbidden based in roles if the users does not login first.

Comment: @dreamcrash , Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, all existing users can login into the admin console. I use a third-party Identity Provider, and any user from this idp can login into admin console. If this user is logged in one of realm's client, he has access to admin console also. And I don't know, how to forbid anybody but admins login into admin console. Can you please help me to do that? I'm new in keycloak

Comment: Strange normally, by default users don't have access to it., Can the users see the master realm? or just a specific realm? with KC version are u using?

Comment: @dreamcrash , yes, all the users can see the Master realm and can also login into it's admin console. I use the same third-party Identity Provide in all the realms. It was not me, who set all the realms up, but it's me, who must fix this problem. :)

Comment: @dreamcrash , I'm using 7.0.1 Keycloak version

Comment: Are those users being imported to the master realm? is the IdP configured in the master realm?

Comment: This idp is configured in all the realms, including Master. Those users are imported automatically during login (the users are from idp, and It is possible to login into admin console, using any idp user's credentials).

Comment: In the master realm, go to users, select one the users that can automatically login as admin, go to role Mapping, which effective roles do they have?

Comment: They all have ${role_admin} and ${role_create-realm} roles, but the Assigned Roles list is empty. The same  imported automatically users in other realms have offline_access and uma_authorization roles only, but they can login into these realms admin console (by auth/admin/realm_name/console/ url)

Comment: In master tab roles, default roles, which are the Realm Default Roles?

Comment: offline_access and uma_authorization only

Comment: In Identity Providers, which type of provider do you have, and when you click on it and go to Mappers, do you have any role mapper?

Comment: I use esia idP, it's our national idp, and when I click on it, I have /notfound pade. The mapper is a custom java application, that is deployed on keycloak's standalone. It doesn't set user roles, but user attrubutes. I was told just now that there is one more keycloak side mapper, and I need some time to find it,s url to check if it changes user roles.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that the problem was because of realms' default groups. I checked them out and there was admin role by default in all the realms' default groups. For this reason, all imported from a third-party idp users had the admin role by default and had access to the admin console.